# an array question

Tags: c#, arrays

i have an array below

```
string stringArray = new stringArray[12];

stringArray[0] = "0,1";
stringArray[1] = "1,3";
stringArray[2] = "1,4";
stringArray[3] = "2,1";
stringArray[4] = "2,4";
stringArray[5] = "3,7";
stringArray[6] = "4,3";
stringArray[7] = "4,2";
stringArray[8] = "4,8";
stringArray[9] = "5,5";
stringArray[10] = "5,6";
stringArray[11] = "6,2";
```

i need to transform like below

```
List<List<string>> listStringArray = new List<List<string>>();

listStringArray[["1"],["3","4"],["1","4"],["7"],["3","2","8"],["5","6"],["2"]];
```

how is that possible?

Comment: Im not following what you want this transformation to do ... how does the input relate to the output?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that he wants the output to be grouped together by the first number in the input strings (i.e. "1, 3" and "1, 4" get put into the same bucket.)

Comment: Ahh, so there is a typo in the input data it should start with "1,1"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think what you actually want is probably this:

```
var indexGroups = x.Select(s => s.Split(',')).GroupBy(s => s[0], s => s[1]);
```

This will return the elements as a grouped enumeration.

To return a list of lists, which is what you literally asked for, then try:

```
var lists = x.Select(s => s.Split(',')).GroupBy(s => s[0], s => s[1])
             .Select(g => g.ToList()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no shorthand like that.  You'll have to break into a loop and split each array and add to the list.

Comment: Enter the great and powerful LINQ! :P

Answer (score 0):

Non LINQ version (I must admit its much uglier, but you may have no choice)

```
        var index = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        foreach (var str in stringArray) {
            string[] split = str.Split(',');
            List<string> items;
            if (!index.TryGetValue(split[0], out items)) {
                items = new List<string>();
                index[split[0]] = items;
            }
            items.Add(split[1]); 
        }

        var transformed = new List<List<string>>();
        foreach (List<string> list in index.Values) {
            transformed.Add(list); 
        }
```